# SQL20448N "05/09/2016" cannot be interpreted using format string "YYYY-MM-DD" for the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function

Tags: db2-9.7

I am getting below error in db2 when executing the sql query-

> SQL20448N  "05/09/2016" cannot be interpreted using format string
>   "YYYY-MM-DD" for the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function.

here is my sql qyery-

```
SELECT DLR_CD,
       FIN ,
       YEAR(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE ,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-YEAR(TO_DATE(CRTNG_DTE,'YYYY-MM-DD'))
       AS AGE 
FROM ASPECT.RO_CAR_PARK_EXTRACT WHERE YEAR = PARM_YEAR
```

what could be the reason for this?

Database - DB2 v9.7.200.358
Platform-  home basic 7

Answer (score 5):

The error message is very clear. I suppose the type of `CRTNG_DTE` is text/varchar and at least one of the values is not in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format (`05/09/2016` clearly isn't!) and the conversion `TO_DATE(CRTNG_DTE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` fails.

The only unclear in the message is the mention of `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT()` function. This part of the [DB2 docs, function `TO_DATE()`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007109.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-158) clears that:

> The `TO_DATE` scalar function is a **synonym** for the `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` scalar function.

The confusion may stem from wrong assumptions about what the `TO_DATE()` function does.

The `TO_DATE(CRTNG_DTE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` is trying to convert strings **that have** the format `YYYY-MM-DD` **to a date**. The dates internal format is irrelevant and you cannot modify it. You cannot choose what format the dates are internally saved as.

Their internal format is a representation of date that is different from DBMS to DBMS and may also change from version to version. And developers need not care what that representation is!

---

Another issue is the first conversion:

```
YEAR(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Since `TO_DATE()` is expecting a string (to be converted) and a format string but you pass to the function a date and a format string, DB2 converts first the date value (`CURRENT_DATE`) to a string (I guess using the default in your installation output format of `MM/DD/YYYY`) so it then tries to calculate:

```
TO_DATE('05/09/2016', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

which of course fails for the same reason as described above.

---

So, to solve the issue (or issues):

- Use `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)` instead for the first calculation.
- Make sure that all values of the `CRTNG_DTE` column have been saved with the format (`'YYYY-MM-DD'`) you expect.